# How to bind value with $scope to view with ng-model from controller that define in state ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I used mechanism for transferring state ui-router. With state "inputcontract" that I have defined, when processed (http://cem.survey.local/#/inputcontract/SGD621262), it will pass parameter "sohd" to function "$scope.getSurveyContent($scope,sohd)" in controller "accountController" , this function will send the request to the server to retrieve data returns in json structures. The problem is that I cannot bind value to view by using $scope with json return "$scope.account =response.data_cusinfo[0]", if bind successfully it will appear dynamic on view HTML. How can i do that? Thank you very much.

Here is app.js

```
var app = angular.module('outbound', ['ngMaterial', 'ui.router'])
    .constant('API_URL', 'http://cem.survey.local/');
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
        .state('inputcontract', {
            url: "/inputcontract/:sohd",
           controller: 'accountController'
        })
})
```

Here is accountController.js

```
app.controller('accountController', function ($scope, $http,$templateRequest, $sce, $compile, $mdDialog, $mdSidenav, $mdMedia, API_URL, $stateParams) {
if (typeof $stateParams.sohd === 'undefined') {
return;
}
$scope.account = {};
var sohd=$stateParams.sohd;
$scope.getSurveyContent= function($scope,sohd)
{   var url = API_URL + "account/search";    
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {sohd: sohd},
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).success(function (response) {
      $scope.account =response.data_cusinfo[0];
    }).error(function (response) {

    });
}
 //Send Request to server with sohd
 $scope.getSurveyContent($scope,sohd);
```

Here is the view

```
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="outbound">
...
<div  ng-controller="accountController">
...
<td style="width: 150px">Khách hàng
   <div class="form-group">
   <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text"
    ng-model="account.CustomerName"  >
   </div></td>
      <td>CMND
       <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text"
      ng-model="account.Passport" >
    </div>
     </td>
       <td>Ngày tháng năm sinh
     <div class="form-group">
   <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text"
     ng-model="account.Birthday">
      </div></td>
...
</div>
...
</html>
```

Comment: can you please json data you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `$http` post is successful, you don't need to pass `$scope` on your `getSurveyContent` function. Also, `success` and `error` are deprecated - you should use `then`. Try this:

```
$scope.getSurveyContent = function(sohd) {   
    var url = API_URL + "account/search";    
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: {sohd: sohd},
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).then(
        function successCallback (response) {
            $scope.account = response.data.data_cusinfo[0];
        }, 
        function errorCallback (response) {
        }
    );
}

//Send Request to server with sohd
$scope.getSurveyContent(sohd);
```